# How do I preseed the installer to use a specific locale?

Tags: language-support, ubiquity, locale, preseed

I am doing a preseed (actually only ask the keyboard map and timezone) of Lucid Lynx install and trying to use the same locale that I selected in the boot screen, I.E. if I select french lang I want to set the same when Ubiquity starts and see the Ubiquity slideshow in the locale previously selected.

I did a little test, edit the file langlist in the isolinux directory removing all the languages that I don't need, and replaced fr with fr_FR.UTF-8 and surprise! all the Ubiquity screen shows in french, the problem was when the installer finished the language in the OS was english :(

Anyone has tried this before? any clue? howto? manual?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ubuntu Customization Kit in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Details on the customization kit are on http://uck.sourceforge.net/ It should pretty much solve your needs.

The manual you request is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-using.html

Good luck - what you are attempting to is not a simple thing to do without a manual :-)